# Determining types of conic sections

Tags: geometry

I have here three equations
$$1.  \space  x^2+xy-6y^2+x-7y-3=0$$
$$ 2.\space x^2+5xy+6y^2+2x+6y=0 $$
$$3. \space x^2+2xy+y^2-4x-4y-4=0$$
and I want to determine what kind of conic sections they are.

So the general form of a conic section is $q(x,y)=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f=0,$

and the Matrix $Q= \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b& c \end{pmatrix}.$

I thought that if $\det Q  = 0 \rightarrow $ parabola, if $\det Q < 0 \rightarrow $ hyperbole, $\det Q >0  \rightarrow$ ellipse .

If I take the first equation $x^2+xy-6y^2+x-7y-3=0,$ is $Q= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 6 \end{pmatrix} =6-(1/4) >0?$

So it should be an ellipse, but by plotting it it looks like a hyperbola.
Why is my way not working? How can I determine the right kind of cone section? And what is the easiest way to see that?

Comment: It should be $Q= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & -6 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Ahh ! thank you ! By plotting the second and third equation I get lines..is that right??

Comment: Yes. Find $x$ from equations 2 and 3 as a function of $y$

Comment: Yes, two secant lines and two parallel lines. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic